# Is it possible to get null from getString using JSONLib

Tags: java, json

I'm using [JSON-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) to parse an object and read a string from it.  This works fine for a valid string but it can also be null.  For example:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject("{\"foo\":null}");
String str = jsonObject.getString("foo");
```

In this case I would expect `str` to be `null` but it is instead `"null"`.  Calling any other method seems to throw an error.  Is there anyway to have JSONLib parse a string if the value is a string but return null if the value is null?

Comment: Is that the real source code?  The "argument" to the fromObject call doesn't look like valid Java.

Comment: quite right, I'll update

Comment: JSONLib is crap. Use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) instead.

Comment: So you called `.getString()`, which returns a `String`, and you expected something other than a string?

Comment: @jsumners Why is it so absurd to you that .getString() could return NULL?  String extends Object, right, and Objects can be equal to NULL?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Because the documentation says so - http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html#getString(java.lang.String)

Comment: Use the .get() method and trap the error that will be thrown when a value is null.

Answer (score 3):

JSONObject.java:

```
/**
* Get the string associated with a key.
*
* @param key A key string.
* @return A string which is the value.
* @throws JSONException if the key is not found.
*/
public String getString( String key ) {
    verifyIsNull();
    Object o = get( key );
    if( o != null ){
        return o.toString();
    }
    throw new JSONException( "JSONObject[" + JSONUtils.quote( key ) + "] not found." );
}
```

You can see that getString() never return null. It can return "null" if o.toString() do that but this will be String not null value

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a nice way to do this, so I did switch to [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) instead.  This allows me to do:

```
JsonNode json = (new ObjectMapper()).readValue("{\"foo\":null}", JsonNode.class);
json.get("stopType").getTextValue();
```

Which will return `null` for this example, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug of JSONLib which has been reported .

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/issues/5

Upgrading your jsonlib to latest version will probably fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make use of JSONObject::opt? You'll get a null (not "null") if the key doesn't exist.

```
String str = (String) jsonObject.opt("foo");
```